# Why is geom_smooth not plotting? (insufficient unique values error)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to compare historical daily attendance figures between the Mariners and White Sox.

I created my data frame with MySQL database and whittled it down to these columns: `date`, `hometeam`, `dayofweek`, and attendance.

I then used `lubridate` to convert the number that encodes the date into a `Date` field in R. I also set the attendance of games reporting 0 to NA. I did both with:

```
sea_attendance <- sea_attendance %>%
  mutate(the_date = ymd(date),
         attendance = ifelse(attendance == 0, NA, attendance))
```

I tried to plot it with this:

```
ggplot(sea_attendance,
       aes(x = wday(the_date), y = attendance,
           color = hometeam)) +
  geom_jitter(height = 0, width = 0.2, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_y_continuous("Attendance") +
  scale_x_continuous("Day of the Week", breaks = 1:7,
                    labels = wday(1:7, label = TRUE)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "grey"))
```

It came out pretty cool, but I couldn't get `geom_smooth` to work:

[image: jittered plot of attendance by week]

I got this error:

```
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam' and formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
Warning messages:
1: Removed 44 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth). 
2: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
x has insufficient unique values to support 10 knots: reduce k. 
3: Removed 44 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

This is a problem out of a textbook. I've been staring at it for an hour trying to figure out where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Could you give us a minimal reproducible example, or the output from `dput(sea_attendance)` please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need something like

```r
geom_smooth(method="gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k=5))
```

`ggplot2` (calling the `mgcv` package) is trying to compute a smooth curve through 7 unique x-values (before jittering), and the default number of "knots" (spline breakpoints) is set to 10.

You could also use an alternate `geom_smooth()` method (e.g. `method="loess"` or `method="lm"` (although the latter will give you a linear fit; you could make it polynomial with e.g. `formula = y ~ poly(x,3)`), or use `stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line")` to connect the means of the groups with a line ...

Related posts (useful, but not necessarily answered clearly):

- [R : stat_smooth error cause by sufficient unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233148/r-stat-smooth-error-cause-by-sufficient-unique-values)
- [R : stat_smooth groups (x axis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208670/r-stat-smooth-groups-x-axis/30209425#30209425)
- [Passing arguments to ggplot and facet_grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606519/passing-arguments-to-ggplot-and-facet-grid)